# create a new column with unique value respective to other value in pyspark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I have a dataframe with column item_id

Below is the sample dataframe

```
+-----------+
|item_id    |
+-----------+
|     BA2C31|
|     BA2C31|
|     B4D456|
|     B4D456|
|     EDJJ88|
+-----------+

from pyspark.sql import functions as F
df = spark.createDataFrame(
    [(0, 'BA2C31'),
     (1, 'BA2C31'),
     (2, 'B4D456'),
     (3, 'B4D456'),
     (4, 'EDJJ88')],
    ['id', 'item_id'])
```

I need to create a column with unique values respective to its item_id...each item_id should have a unique value

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import col, sha2, concat

df.withColumn("u_id", sha2(col("item_id")), 256)).show(10, False)
```

Desired output:

```
+--------------------+
|item_id    | u_id
+--------------------+
|     BA2C31| 101
|     BA2C31| 101
|     B4D456| 102
|     B4D456| 102
|     EDJJ88| 103
+--------------------+
```

I am using withcolumn..but I am not getting the desired output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [dense_rank()](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/sql/index.html#dense_rank),

```
from pyspark.sql.window import Window
from pyspark.sql.functions import dense_rank

df.withColumn("u_id", dense_rank().over(Window.orderBy("item_id")) + 100).show()

+---+-------+----+
| id|item_id|u_id|
+---+-------+----+
|  2| B4D456| 101|
|  3| B4D456| 101|
|  0| BA2C31| 102|
|  1| BA2C31| 102|
|  4| EDJJ88| 103|
+---+-------+----+
```